# How to use both blank and default date in date_select in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, form-helpers

The following code works as expected, using the @the_date as the default selected date.

```
<%= date_select("the_date", "", :default => @the_date ) %>
```

However, in the case there is no date, it needs to show blanks. The following code displays blanks, but also forces the default selection to be blank even when the date is defined.

```
<%= date_select("patient_details[birth_date]", "", { :default => @the_date, :include_blank => true } ) %>
```

How do you set the default selection to a date, and to blank if the date is nil?

Working in Rails 3.07.

Thanks.

Comment: First of all, you should probably write your thing like: `date_select(:patient_details, :birth_date, { :default => @the_date, :include_blank => true })`, it fits better with the semantics of the call as written in the documentation. Now in terms of your issue, if it actually behaves like you say (can't check just now that I can reproduce), I would consider it is a bug in rails.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just, :include_blank => @the_date.nil? , it should do the trick. See example below

`date_select(:patient_details, :birth_date, { :default => @the_date, :include_blank=> @the_date.nil? })`

Comment: Just? It worked, but there is no way to choose a blank once the date is entered. How to handle the use case of when the user wants to delete an existing date?

Answer (score 11):

Rails [ignores your `:default`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b8f6fccae3af30fa2ee612e8cff4c2243e95e24f/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/date_select.rb#L43) if you also use either `:include_blank` or `:prompt`.

IMO this is a bug but there we go.